# ¿Como mantener una solicitud HTTP hasta que devuelva un resultado esperado? C#

Tags: api, http, async

Tengo que consultar un servicio web a un endpoint por el método GET. Este servicio me devuelve un estado de como se encuentra la subscripción, tiene varios como "En proceso", "Subscrito" y "Completado". La cuestión es que después de suscribir un producto a este servicio, toma alrededor de 1 minuto en que el estado pase de "En proceso" a "Completado". Yo tengo que guardar la información que responde cuando el estado es "Completado", que es donde se genera toda la data necesaria pero, lo estaba haciendo mediante un ciclo while, consultando por el estado que devuelve. El problema es que hay veces que entra en un ciclo infinito y no tengo respuesta luego en mi controlador.

Algo asi estaba haciendo:

```
var bandera = true;
while(bandera){
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    //Parseo el objeto a una clase y pregunto
   if(clase.Estado == "Completado"){
    // Guardo la información con EntityFramework
    bandera = false;
   }
}
```

Esto funciona bien ciertas veces, pero cuando demora demasiado la respuesta, se queda en un ciclo infinito y no termina nunca de recibir el estado. ¿De que manera puedo realizar esta solicitud hasta obtener ese estado muchas veces sin caer en un bucle infinito?

Comment: Importante, lo tenía que decir. No es recomendable mezclar inglés y castellano en código siempre que se pueda evitar, aunque lo veas en otros compañeros, se consistente, es mas profesional. ;). Te animo a investigar/debug la pregunta del millón ¿Porque cuando tarda mucho (timeout) queda en bucle infinito? Si solucionas ese punto no solo lo conseguirás, sino que además irás mas allá y comprender como manejar llamadas asíncronas y posibles timeout. Además revisaría ese "parseo" ¿Conoces Promise.all()? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Gracias, Investigaré mucho mas